# List fails to wrap with 'flex-flow' set to 'row wrap'

Tags: css

At small browser widths my nav menu is not wrapping:

[image]

Adding `!important` to the `flex-flow` rule does nothing.

What is the answer to making nav items wrap correctly?

I am considering doing away with the list, using a `div` container instead, and converting each item to use `p` tags.

Here are the css rules for the container, which is the `<ul>` tag.

```
const NavList = styled.ul`
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
`
```

The syntax is from React.js's styled components library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `flex-flow: row wrap;` without the dash.